# What happens with your github page(s) when you change your account name?

Tags: github, account

Wondering what happen when you change the name in your account; what happens with your `username/github.io` page? Your pages show 404?

The pages are corrected by github automatically with your new name so they are still usable or what?

*Need an answer cause I'm about to switch names.*

I'm about to try, this is a question only.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question, not a programming question.

Comment: this sounds like a question for *github*